# @Inject fields are all null inside mocked object

Tags: android, mockito, viewmodel, android-espresso, dagger-2

I'm trying to write a UI test using Espresso, I have a view model that I need to mock. But inside this mocked viewmodel there're several `@Inject` fields that are null, which causing all sorts of trouble.

Here's the view model itself (Names changed and stuff for simplicity but the code is exactly the same)

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MyFieldRepository myFieldRepository;

    @Inject
    public MyViewModel(MyFieldRepository myField) {
        this.myFieldRepository = myField; //remains null
    }

    public void start() { //NPE here
        myFieldRepository.startAPI() //... async call code
    }
}
```

And the view model Dagger Module

```
@Module
public class MyViewModelModule {
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MyViewModel.class)
    public ViewModel providesMyViewModel() {
        MyViewModel myViewModel = Mockito.mock(MyViewModel.class);
        return pinPadViewModel;
    }
}
```

And finally the field module (that I wanted to be injected)

```
@Module
public class MyFieldRepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @AppScoped
    public MyFieldRepository providesMyField() {
        MyFieldRepository myField = Mockito.mock(MyFieldRepository.class);
        return myField;
    }
}
```

And here's the component code:

```
@AppScoped
@Component(modules = {
        MyViewModelModule.class,
        MyFieldModule.class,
})

public interface TestAppComponent extends AndroidInjector<TestApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        TestAppComponent build();
    }
}
```

I want to find a way for `myField` to be injected by Dagger using `MyFieldModule`.

Comment: Can you share Component code?

Comment: @VishalPawar done

Comment: Are you sure about the mockito tag in your question? It doesn't  look like your question is related to JUnit testing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use ViewModelProvider.Factory to provide dependency

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}
```